# Pass Data to SearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have 2 viewController that is liked to each other. First viewController has a collectionView as button, so when you click the collectionView it will direct you to the second viewContoller through segue.

```
  @IBAction func presedCollectionViewButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
  }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! AllCategoriesViewController
    destinationVC.filterText = test

}
```

Then I passed data to a searchBar that in the second controllView in order to filter the tableView once the perform segue is executed, but it does not filter the tableView directly and in order to see the filterText that I passed I have to click on the searchBar in the viewController.

```
extension AllCategoriesViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

     func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBar.text = filterText
        filteredCategory = allcotegoryLabel.filter({$0.categoryName.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
        isSearch = true
        allCategoriesTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isSearch = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        allCategoriesTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

So my question is how to solve this issue and let it filter the tableView once the preform segue is executed?

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "allCategories", for: indexPath) as! allCategoriesTableViewCell
    if isSearch {
       cell.allCategoriesLabel.text = filteredCategory[indexPath.row].categoryName
    } else {
       cell.allCategoriesLabel.text = allcotegoryLabel[indexPath.row].categoryName
    }
    return cell
}
```

here is some usage of isSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the search bar text to a variable not the search bar. Then, set the search bar text in the `viewDidLoad()` method, after that refresh the tableView in the `viewDidLoad`. If that doesn't work you can try the same thing in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: still I need to click on the searchbar in order to filter the tableview, I think I need to change textDidChange method but what is the alternative. @Luc

Comment: @Saleh96 What is the isSearch bool for? That seems a little odd to me

Comment: I have two arrays (filteredCategory) and (allcotegoryLabel) for the tableview .(filteredCategory) have the filtered result, so I used isSearch to check if the user is searching then display (filteredCategory) in tableview and if not display (allcotegoryLabel). I have edited the question to show some usage of isSearch. @Luc

Comment: @Saleh96 The problem is `textDidChange` doesn’t run until the User interacts with the search bar. The work around would be setting the data for the table view and then the text for the search bar separately. You can’t rly on `textDidChange` To set the tables view filter when the view loads. Basically setting the searchbar Text does not count as the text changing.

Comment: Glad to help! 